# Facebook login loads landing page inside popup window

Tags: facebook

After signing up to my site as a new member, redirect page is loaded inside the FB login popup window. And I can not figure it out.

```
if (!session_id()) session_start();
        $_SESSION['userid']     = $user_id;
        $_SESSION['FirstName']  = $fname;
        $_SESSION['loginFb']    = $logoutUrl;
        header("Location: sign-up/welcome");
        echo "<script>
            window.close();
            window.opener.location.reload();
            </script>";
        exit();
```

How should the code has to be corrected in order to get the redirection page in the main browser?

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location: sign-up/welcome");
```

In general PHP executed before HTML, CSS and JS does that's why, remove it and it should work

```
if (!session_id()) session_start();
        $_SESSION['userid']     = $user_id;
        $_SESSION['FirstName']  = $fname;
        $_SESSION['loginFb']    = $logoutUrl;
        echo "<script>
            window.close();
            window.opener.location.reload();
            </script>";
        exit();
```